# In GraphQL, is it better to differentiate object relationship with an attribute or a relation?

Tags: graphql

Let's say (imaginary situation) I have a user that owns books and that can also contribute to books.

To find out the books that are owned by the current user I could simply query them like this:

```graphql
viewer {
  id
  books {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

`viewer` is of GraphQl type `User` and books returns an array of GraphQl type `Book`.

What if I want to query the books that the user contributes to? Since they are still books, I imagine that I would still use the `Book` type, but how do I differentiate owned books from books that the user has contributed to? It seems like there are two options:

a) Attribute

- easier for client since I can find a book the user has access to just by specifying `books(:id)`

```graphql
viewer {
  id
  books {
    id
    title
    userIsContributor
  }
}
```

b) Different relationship

- easier for the server since that reflects more closely the DB schema, where a user is associated with a book with the `user_id` column or the `contributors` join table, depending if the user is the main author or just a contributor.

```graphql
viewer {
  id
  books {
    id
    title
  }
  contributedToBooks {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

Is there a canonical way to achieve this or something I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit-opinion based so here goes:

```
type Person {
  id: ID!
  booksOwned: [Books]
  booksContributedTo: [Books]
}

type Book {
  id: ID!
  contributors: [Person]
  ownedBy: [Person]
}
```

In this way you can follow either relationship in either direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is the solution I went with, the only "problem" is that now in the frontend I pretty much always have to pair a book id with a `owned/contributedTo` boolean because otherwise I wouldn't know what query to execute when I need the data in another component.

Comment: Your front-end use cases really drive your schema. If you need an `isOwner` or `isContributor` boolean relative to the current user then add it!